# "Schmiedeeffekt" auf Deutsch

Tags: translation, single-word-request, idiomaticity

Ich übersetze für einen Blog einen Text aus dem Ukrainischen ins Deutsche und habe aber eine Herausforderung mit der Übersetzung des Ausdrucks "Schmiedeeffekt". Der vollständige, übersetzte Absatz:

> Die Pedalunterstützung-Funktion ist mit einem Elektromotor ausgestattet, der einer Person beim E-Bike fahren hilft. Das heißt, eine Person tritt immer mit der gleichen Kraft in die Pedale - bergauf, bergab, was auch immer. Es spielt keine Rolle, wie alt die Person ist. Der Kraftaufwand ist immer gleich. **Es gibt einen sogenannten Schmiedeeffekt.** Das heißt, jeder weiß, dass ein Schmied dreißig Jahre lang mit einem Hammer draufhaut und immer dünn bleibt. Denn jedermann gewöhnt sich an der Belastung.

Ich weiß nicht, ob ein solcher Ausdruck "Schmiedeeffekt" im Deutschen vorhanden ist. Kann mir jemand damit helfen, den Ausdruck zu übersetzen oder sinnvoll zu ergänzen?

Danke!

Comment: *Schmiedeeffekt* habe ich noch nie gehört, ich bin mir auch nicht sicher, welche Bedeutung gefragt ist. Passt *Gewöhnungseffekt* oder *Trainingseffekt*?

Comment: Hi! Danke! Macht Sinn! Grüße nach Fürth aus Fürth-Süd (Ludwigstr.)

Comment: Ich verstehe den Text gar nicht. Meint er "dünn" im Sinne von "normalgewichtig" oder "ohne Muskeln"? Also, zeichnet er die gleichmäßige Belastung in positivem oder negativem Licht? Und wieso wird die tatsächlich total gleichmäßige Bewegung des E-Bikes mit Hämmern verglichen, das ja alles andere als das ist?

Comment: Und wenn es hier egal sein soll, dass Hämmern überhaupt keine gleichmäßige Belastung ist, wieso wird es dann nicht nur zum Vergleich rangezogen, sondern gleich noch das Wort "Schmedeeffekt" gebildet. Warum musste es dieser Vergleich mit dem Schmied sein, wieso reichte nicht "wie jeder weiß, hält regelmäßige körperliche Betätigung schlank, wie man an körperlich Arbeitenden sehen kann." (Was ich aber auch wiederum bezweifeln würde, je nachdem, wie sich der Schmied ernährt.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das Wort "Schmiedeeffekt" gibt es im Deutschen, allerdings in völlig anderer Bedeutung als im ukrainischen Text. Ein Schmiedeeffekt kann bei der Metallverarbeitung auftreten, vgl. z.B. [1](https://www.slv-halle.de/suche?tx_kesearch_pi1%5Bpage%5D=4&tx_kesearch_pi1%5Bsword%5D=wege&cHash=921d74bbdedeac090ec6ca19eb97406e), [2](https://www.recyclinganlagen.info/images/datenblaetter/t_150_komplettanlage.pdf), [3](http://schnabel-bautechnik.de/fileadmin/kataloge/techinfoold/SCHNABEL_GmbH-TechInfo_Eisen-Kohlenstoff-Diagramm.pdf). Das Wort wird auch für eine bestimmtes Aussehen einer (ggf. lackierten) Metalloberfäche verwendet; vgl. [4](https://www.besserlackieren.de/artikel/archiv/dreifachschutz), [5](https://www.swisstime.ch/de-watches-HYT-Skull-Bad-Boy-p3390.html), [6](http://www.cibins.eu/produkte/detail/products/cibins-rest-al/backPID/baenke.html), [7](https://www.layup.ch/mtn-pro-schmiedeeffekt-spray-400ml-p-15887.html).

Wie guidot in seinem Kommentar anmerkt, handelt es im Kontext der Frage um einen Trainingseffekt, der durch langzeitige, ausdauernde und gleichmäßige körperliche Betätigung erreicht wird. Das Wort "Trainingseffekt" sollte allerdings sinnvoll mit dem Wort "Schmied" im nächsten Satz verbunden werden. Vorschlag:

> Es gibt dadurch einen Trainingseffekt wie beispielsweise bei einem Schmied, der dreißig Jahre lang mit einem Hammer auf Metall schlägt und dadurch immer fit und schlank bleibt. Denn jedermann gewöhnt sich an eine gleichmäßige Belastung.